# File was not uploading in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am uploading images in codeigniter. my file is not getting uploaded. i dont know where i am doing wrong. please find in below code

Html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assign_user/addStartPopup">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="image">
                            <input type="radio" id="image" name="start_img" onclick="rightfilefunction(1);" checked> <label for="image"> <span style="top: -2px;position: relative;">Image upload</span></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <label for="video" class="green">
                            <input type="radio" id="video" name="start_img" onclick="rightfilefunction(2);">
                            <span style="top: -2px;position: relative;">Video</span>
                            </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" id="imageId">
                                <input type="file" name="imageupload" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" id="videoId" style="display:none">
                                <input type="text" name="video_upload" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Save </button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Model:

```
public function startPopup(){
    $createdOn = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if($_FILES['imageupload']['size'] != 0)
    {
        $files = $_FILES;
        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path'] = "startpage/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = "png|jpg|gif"; 
        $config['max_size'] = "5000";
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload('imageupload')){
        $imgdata = $this->upload->data();
        $image_config=array();          
        $image_config["image_library"] = "gd2";
        $image_config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $image_config["source_image"] = $imgdata["full_path"];
        $image_config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $image_config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $image_config['new_image'] = $imgdata["file_path"].$imgdata["file_name"];
        $image_config['quality'] = "95%";
        $image_config['width'] = 170;
        $image_config['height'] = 170;
        $this->load->library('image_lib',$image_config);
        $this->image_lib->initialize($image_config);    
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $logo = 'startpage/'.$imgdata["file_name"];

        $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `startpop` (content_view, created_on) VALUES ('$logo', '$createdOn')");
        if($query){
            return 1;
        }
    }else
    {
        echo "not uploaded";
    }
    }else{
    $prv = $this->input->post('video_upload');
    $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `startpop` (content_view, created_on) VALUES ('$prv', '$createdOn')");
    if($query){
        return 1;
    }
}
}
```

Controller:

```
public function addStartPopup(){
    $result = $this->model->startPopup();
    if($result > 0){
        $data['mgs'] = "Added Successfully ..!";
        $this->load->view('admin/startPage',$data);
    }

}
```

From this above code, i am getting the error "not uploaded". can any one tell me where i am doing wrong

Comment: try with `if($_FILES['imageupload']['size'] > 0)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply my code is coming in this if($_FILES['imageupload']['size'] > 0) while upload i am getting "not uploaded " echo message from above code if($this->upload->do_upload('imageupload')){ echo "not uploaded" }

Comment: you write _i am getting the error "not uploaded"_ so i just check it

Comment: Yes you are are right......i dont know where i am mistaking ?

Comment: just change file name to `userfile` and try

Comment: I am getting same error brother.....same task i have done for another page, image got uploaded here my code not working, i know i am doing small mistake, but i cannot find where i am having.